# Different results from pandas groupby and pivot_table when dtype is categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I ran in to this earlier today when creating pivot tables after categorizing a column of values using `pd.cut`. When creating the pivot tables I was finding that the subsequent index was incorrect. This was not an issue when using `groupby` instead, or after converting the category column to a different dtype.

Simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
                   , 'g1': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
                   , 'vals': [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]})
df['l2'] = pd.cut(df.vals, bins=[0, 2, 4], labels=['l', 'h'])
df = df[['l1', 'l2', 'g1', 'vals']]
```

Using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['l1', 'l2', 'g1']).vals.agg(('sum', 'count')).unstack()[['count', 'sum']]

         count   sum   
g1        1  2   1  2
l1 l2                
a  l      1  1   1  1
   h      1  1   3  3
b  l      2  2   4  4
   h      1  1   3  3
```

Using `pd.pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['l1', 'l2'], columns='g1', aggfunc=('sum', 'count'))

         vals          
         count   sum   
g1        1  2   1  2
l1 l2                
a  h      1  1   1  1
   l      1  1   3  3
b  h      2  2   4  4
   l      1  1   3  3
```

Using `pd.pivot_table` after converting the `l2` column to `str` dtype:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['l2'] = df2.l2.astype(str)
pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['l1', 'l2'], columns='g1', aggfunc=('sum', 'count'))

         vals          
         count  sum   
g1        1  2   1  2
l1 l2                
a  h      1  1   3  3
   l      1  1   1  1
b  h      1  1   3  3
   l      2  2   4  4
```

The order in the last example is reversed, but the values are correct (in contrast to the middle example, where the order is reversed and the values are incorrect).

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  Seems to work in 0.23.3.

Comment: Using version 0.23.0

Comment: Bug could have been fixed, or could still be there and other changes just make it manifest differently.  Let me see if I can isolate the version.

Comment: Appears to work properly in 0.22.0 as well.

Comment: Okay, seems to work for me in every pandas version >= 0.22.0 at hand _except for_ 0.23.0.  I don't immediately see what change would be [relevant](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0231-bug-fixes).  (And, again, it's possible the bug wasn't actually fixed, just hidden.)

Comment: Yeah I was looking through the release notes as well, and didn't see anything. Can you confirm that it's not working in 0.23.0 for you as well though? I can just update I guess, not sure if it's worth opening a ticket on GH for it.

Comment: Yeah, I confirm it fails in 0.23.0 for me as well.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking